# Ranking a Measure Value (as opposed to a column value) in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

**Short version of question:** how can I create a rank based on a calculated measure?

**Question background:**
I have a table/query that yields many rows for each employee, with each row having a `time taken` value.

I'd like to calculate the average time taken for each `employee`, and then present a table with a row for each `employee`, showing their `name`, average `time taken`, and `rank` (based on `time taken`).

To do the first part, I created a measure called `AverageTimeLength` and set it equal to:

```
AverageTimeLength = Average(Table_name[Column_name])
```

Then I coded the following:

```
AverageTimeLength_employee = CALCULATE([AverageTimeLength], GROUPBY(Table_name, Table_name[EmployeeName]))
```

These two are measures; I was able to insert the second into the new table chart I'm creating, but unfortunately, I can't use `RANKX()` on it because the measure values don't come from a column. If I try to create a column derived from the measure (i.e., `column_name = [AverageTimeLength_employee]`) I just get an error accusing `column_name` of circular reasoning.

What I want to do seems like it should be simple; does anyone know how I can create a simple rank parameter, to rank the measure values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the `Average` measure and use it in the `Rank` measure as follows:

```
Average = AVERAGE([Time taken])
```

```
Rank = IF (
    HASONEVALUE ( Table_Name[Name] ), 
    RANKX ( ALL ( Table_Name[Name] ), [Average])
)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It definitely helped- thanks. If you don't mind, I have a couple further questions about the `RANKX()` function: (1) if there's a tie between two employees, how can I insert a tie breaker, and (2) I noticed that the rank works perfectly if there are no other filters I've placed; how do I get the rank to consider only the entries that are filtered?

Comment: @daOnlyBG, (1) It is possible to customize the rank criteria, either creating a calculated column and using it in the rankx function or using the rankx _value_ parameter, without knowing the logic to determine the breaker there is no much we can say. (2) You can make the measure sensible to filters by changing `ALL(Table_Name[Name])` by  `ALLSELECTED(Table_Name[Name])`.

Comment: I do have a column that would be something like "Employee Successes." That would be the tie breaker- I'll have to see how I can use it inside the `RANKX()` function.